# How to refresh an uploaded data source for a report created in Power BI web app?

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I created a Power BI report using the Power BI website interface at app.powerbi.com. My data source is an Excel table that I uploaded to the web app. Now I need to update the source data. However, it appears that my data cannot be edited in the web app, or updated using the refresh button, or replaced with a new data source. Is my only option to upload a new data set and start re-building the report from scratch? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are in an unfortunate dead end. I would start again using Power BI Desktop to get the Excel data. Then for each page, you can flip to Edit mode in a browser session, copy all the visuals on the page at once and paste them into Power BI Desktop.

You can save a PBIX file from Power BI Desktop, and it has a Publish button to push the report and dataset to the web service.  It also has a Refresh button to reload the data from Excel.